# SailsJs: if I need to mix data from 2 unrelated Models, should I do it inside a Model or in a Controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js

I have 2 Models:

- Product
- Currency

There is no relationship between the corresponding tables of both models in the database (and there shouldn't be).

When I request a Product I need to return it's price in multiple Currencies. For that I will need to read all currencies from the database using the Currency Model.

Should I select records from both Models inside a method in **Product's Controller** and then calculate the prices using properties from the objects read from the database or should I read the currencies from inside a method in **Product's Model** and then do the same operation?

Comment: It's not really a sails question, more a general MVC coding one. Models are just data representation and it must not do anything relating with other model. The good way is to do it in your controllers (or services)

Answer (score 2):

Your priorities should be 1) eliminating duplication of code and 2) organizing code in a way that will be easy to maintain.  If every time you look up a product, you'll also want its price in multiple currencies, then a `Product` class method called `findProductWithPrices` is perfectly appropriate.  If it's only ever going to be needed from the one endpoint in `ProductController`, then placing the logic in the controller will probably make it easier to keep track of.

Another option, depending on how often you'll end up doing these calculations, would be to add a `prices` attribute to `Product` with a `json` type, and make it a cached dictionary of currency->price.  Then you only have to do these calculations (and update `prices`) when the price of a product changes.

Comment: The cache suggestion is a nice one! I was thinking about caching the currencies objects because they rarely change, but I was forgetting that prices also don't change much. I'll google what is a good way of implementing that cache, but any suggestions will be appreciated :-)

Comment: Having a `prices` attribute on the `Product` model is part of a cache implementation (the storage).  The remaining part would be making sure the cache is updated, which you could do several ways, including using the `beforeUpdate` and `beforeCreate` [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) to reset the `prices` attribute whenever the main price of a product changes.